# How to Parse Toml Data to Json Data?

Tags: c++

I want to parse TOML data in JSON format. I also want a variable that contains TOML data and another variable that contains JSON data.

```
json Services::getJsonData(std::string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        _data_table = toml::parse(filePath);
        // std::cout << toml::json_formatter{_data_table} << "\n";
        std::stringstream strm;
        strm << toml::json_formatter{data};
        json json_data = json::parse(strm);
        std::cout << json_data << endl;
    }
    catch (const toml::exception &err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Parsing failed:\n"
                  << err.what() << "\n";
        std::runtime_error(err.what());
    }
}
```

https://marzer.github.io/tomlplusplus/classtoml_1_1json__formatter.html

Comment: Sadly I know of no freely available translation library. Doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but assuming I could not find one I'd do this the hard way with JSON library, a TOML library and some hand-written glue code in the middle to take the parsed TOML structure and write it into the JSON library.

Comment: can i use ```toml::json_formatter```

Comment: https://marzer.github.io/tomlplusplus/classtoml_1_1json__formatter.html

Comment: Right on. Based on what you have there, `std::stringstream strm; strm << toml::json_formatter{tbl};` and then pass `strm` to [this guy](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/parse/)